# Cannot stream video via library freegal movies

Tags: video, flash

My local library offers free movie streaming via freegalmovies.com

It's a flash-based stream, but for the life of me, I cannot get my Ubuntu 12.04 laptop to play any movies.

Other flash sites work fine.  Youtube, vimeo, et al.
Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sites streaming with DRM on flash require HAL, which is depreciated and not installed in Ubuntu 10.04 (and other recent distros) This can be fixed by installing just the hal library. The adobe flash site gives instructions how to do this: http://helpx.adobe.com/x-productkb/multi/flash-player-11-problems-playing.html.

Comment: Thank you, pihentagyu!  All is well in movie land, now.  :)